# How can Clickhouse local join and local insert on distributed tables?

Tags: clickhouse

I have 3 distributed table: t_user_info_all, t_user_event_all, t_user_flat_all, they all on same cluster with same shard key user_id.

And i want insert join result of t_user_event_all and t_user_info_all into t_user_flat_all, SQL like this:
`insert into t_user_flat_all select * from t_user_info_all t1 left join t_user_event_all t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id`.

With setting [distributed_product_mode](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#distributed-product-mode) = 'local', join runs on local mode, but insert statements still on a distributed table.

I found setting [parallel_distributed_insert_select](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#parallel_distributed_insert_select) = 2, SELECT and INSERT will be executed on each shard from/to the underlying table of the distributed engine. But it only works for queries like `INSERT INTO distributed_table_a SELECT ... FROM distributed_table_b`, the select query **can not** have where conditions or joins.

Or i can run local insert `insert into t_user_flat_local select * from t_user_info_local t1 left join t_user_event_local t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id` on each shard, but it makes the case complex.

Comment: can you execute the query with `on cluster` clause ? `insert into t_user_flat_local select * from t_user_info_local t1 left join t_user_event_local t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id on cluster YOUR_CLUSTER`

Comment: @Yongfeng  on cluster clause is only for ddl, insert or select with on cluster cause Syntax error :(